# Is it a good idea to use static helper classes in Play Framework 2?

Tags: java, playframework, thread-safety

I'm developing a Play Framework 2 application in Java, and I'm wondering if I can use static helper classes.

For example, I want to know if a user is logged and have completed its profile. This test take a few lines, may be subject to change, and is used a lot in the application.

So I write a class with these tests in one method with one argument (the Session object) that I use everywhere.

But I have to instantiate a class each time to use the method, so at scale it may be inefficient. Is it safe to make it static ? If it is, what other play object can I use safely as a parameter ?

Comment: Why are you instantiating a class to use the method? That functionality certainly sounds like a strong candidate for making into a static method. Is it safe... well who knows... we do not know what the method does! What other object can be used safely... I don't really know, I am not entirely sure what your concerns are...

Comment: My problem is : what do I have to check to be sure that a static method (not in a controller) is thread safe in play framework ? In this regard, what play objects (like Request, Session...) are safe to use in this context ? It's a general question, about dos and don'ts, and what is the best way to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "test", I assume you mean some checking logic instead of unit tests.

In that case, you can use dependency injection instead of static helpers.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaInjection

The above link shows an example of how to use [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) to inject your controller when processing requests.

So previously your controller would be:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        if (YourStaticHelper.yourStaticMethod.isOk()) {
            return ok("It works!");
        }
        else {
            return forbidden("NO");
        }
    }

}
```

Now it would become:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    @Inject
    YourStaticHelperInterface checker;

    public Result index() {  // no longer static
        if (checker.isOk()) {
            return ok("It works!");
        }
        else {
            return forbidden("NO");
        }
    }

}
```

The difference is in the previous one if you somehow need a new helper, you would have to change the controller code to adapt it to the change, whereas in the second you just need to inject a different implementation at runtime as isOk() there becomes a contract in the interface.

The benefit? Who knows. If I'm writing something completely myself at home or the controller code is actually tightly coupled with the helper, I would choose the first. If I'm working with others in a company, I would pick the second. It's all about software engineering shit but that's how things work.

Comment: Interesting answer, even if it's not really what I expected.